# get data in a ejs include with express-partials

Tags: node.js, express, layout, include, view

I want to pass data to a include in ejs layout. I'm using express and express-partials

In the controller.js I have this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {uptime:'3'});
};
```

this is layout.ejs:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                  
<html>                                                                            
  <head>                                                                          
    <%- include head %>                                                           
  </head>                                                                         
  <header>                                                                        
    <%- include nav %>                                                            
  </header>                                                                       
  <body>                                                                          
  <section>                                                                       
    <%- body %>                                                                   
  </section>                                                                      
  </body>                                                                         
  <footer>                                                                        
  </footer>                                                                       
</html>
```

this is nav.ejs:

```
<li><%= uptime %></li>
```

and i get this error:

```
    ReferenceError: /root/apps/webpanel/webpanel/views/nav.ejs:23
    21|     </li>
    22|       </ul>
 >> 23|       <li><%= uptime %></li>
    24| 
    25| 
    26| 

uptime is not defined
```

if I put the uptime in index.ejs the error disappears, but I want to get different views for nav and body...

What is the best solution to work correctly? or what i'm doing wrong?:/ 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this code : `res.render('index', { uptime : '3'});`

you choose to render the `index.ejs`

but the `uptime` key in `layout.ejs`

you said `res.render('layout', { uptime: '3'});` does well

You should understand the first param of `.render()` meaning and ensure which template you need to render.

Comment: I want to render two templates, index and nav.
In  `<%- body %> ` is loaded the index template(or whatever that you send).
I want to send the data to all layout, but i don't know if it is possible

Comment: two templates, I dont know what you mean.

Comment: You can use `include` to set two template into one. Each `render()` only have one template.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put in session, for access in some route, somelike:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.uptime = 3;
    res.render('index');
};
```

And:

```
<li><%= session.uptime %></li>
```

Comment: Now I'm using this code `res.locals.uptime = 3;` 
In the html is working and I can see the value, but the console shows again the error `uptime is not defined`